# Fitch proof of Peirce's Law

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

This was a question on my exam today that I couldn't figure out.

Show $((P \supset Q) \supset P) \supset P$ with no premises using Fitch.

The first attempt is I assumed $(P \supset Q) \supset P$. Then I assume $\neg  P$ and attempted to derive a contradiction.

However, I couldn't get anywhere productive. Any hints or direction?

Comment: Hint: under the assumption $\lnot P$, it follows that $P \supset Q$ for any $Q$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Could you lead me to that? I see that using Modus Tollens we can get $\neg(P \supset Q)$. But I don't think that's exactly what you were talking about.

Comment: Well, if you have assumptions $\lnot P, P$ then you can conclude $\bot$ and therefore by *ex falso quodlibet* (explosion principle) $Q$ follows.  So, then by ${\supset} I$ with the assumption $\lnot P$ you conclude $P \supset Q$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh oh oh. Okay. I appreciate it.